# JavaScript in ServiceNow

Tags: javascript, servicenow

I am trying to pass an array to a REST API that takes an array as one of its parameters.

When I stringify the array it converts the array to: ["Acid Reflux,Anemia,Asthma,Atrial Fibrillation,Cancer"] (no quotes around each item within the array) which the API doesn't like.

When I take the original list and convert to an array (using split), it retains the quotes, but the API doesn't want an array (because it is already an array object) and throws an error: [["Acid" Reflux","Anemia","Asthma","Atrial Fibrillation","Cancer"]]

I tried looping through the array to convert each to a string, but this adds an escape character to each item because I am doing regex or replace(',', '","') and it inherently wants to escape the quotes.

At my wits end :/

Comment: How exactly are you stringifying?  Are you calling `JSON.stringify(["some", "cool", "array"])`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `JSON.stringify()`, not `Array.toString()`.  Consider the difference:

```js
const arr = ["some", "cool", "array"];

const str1 = arr.toString();
const str2 = JSON.stringify(arr);

console.log(str1);
console.log(str2);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!